undefined is not an object (evaluating 'axios.create')
I have been trying to integrate razorpay on my website. I have installed razorpay and axios. But upon using :
const Razorpay = require("razorpay");
const client = new Razorpay({
            key_id   : 'xxx',
            key_secret : 'zzz'
        });

I am encountering an error :
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'axios.create')
API@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:75881:20
Razorpay@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:75994:23
@http://localhost:3000/main.7d1790cfe4e83e2ce13c.hot-update.js:72:34
makePayment@http://localhost:3000/main.7d1790cfe4e83e2ce13c.hot-update.js:60:28
callCallback@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:85302:23
dispatchEvent@[native code]
invokeGuardedCallbackDev@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:85346:33
invokeGuardedCallback@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:85403:40
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:85417:34
executeDispatch@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:89560:46
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:89586:26
processDispatchQueue@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:89597:41
dispatchEventsForPlugins@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:89606:27
batchedUpdates$1@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:104150:18
batchedUpdates@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:85150:34
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:89765:21
dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:87272:42
dispatchEvent@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:87266:88
dispatchDiscreteEvent@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:87243:22

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?
Client isn't initialising. I have tries upgrading axios as well.

I've never heard of Razorpay, but a quick check of the package page shows that it's a Node library, so likely won't work in React.
